# How to install 'python3-dev' on Google App Engine to use 'pymatting_aot.aot'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run a Python 3.8 script on Google App Engine that is using `pymatting_aot.aot`

When running this script on my local Ubuntu machine, it works without any issues, but when I tried to run it on GAE, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymatting_aot/cc.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pymatting_aot.aot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatting_aot.aot'
```

This github link: https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/issues/35 , shows that I need to install `python3-dev` to fix the issue via `apt-get install -y python3-dev`

I've tried `sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev` on my GAE console and I got:

```
machine is ephemeral and no system-wide change will persist beyond session end.

To suppress this warning, create an empty ~/.cloudshell/no-apt-get-warning file.
The command will automatically proceed in 5 seconds or on any key.

Visit https://cloud.google.com/shell/help for more information.
********************************************************************************
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.7.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
```

requirements.txt

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
numpy==1.19.4
torch==1.7.0+cpu
torchvision==0.8.1+cpu
pymatting==1.1.1
scikit-image==0.17.2
waitress==1.4.4
scipy==1.5.4
hsh==1.1.0
flask==1.1.2
filetype==1.0.7
matplotlib==3.1.1
tqdm==4.51.0
requests==2.25.0
fastapi==0.62.0
Pillow==8.0.1
skimage==0.0
uvicorn==0.11.6
gunicorn==20.0.4
python-multipart==0.0.5
```

The issue remains,
Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Can you provide requirements.txt also?

Comment: @Jaroslav added requirement file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that pymatting_aot.aot is really not there to be imported and needs to be compiled first.

You can compile the module by importing pymatting_aot.cc in your code first or incorporating this import into your Dockerfile for app engine, so that the container comes with this shared object library precompiled.

Here is a quick rundown to see how it works (or rather to see how it works after compiling it):

```
root@dcda6f2673cb:/# pip install pymatting

Collecting pymatting
  Downloading PyMatting-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 48 kB 1.4 MB/s
Collecting numba!=0.49.0
  Downloading numba-0.52.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2 MB 2.9 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from numba!=0.49.0->pymatting) (51.1.0)
Collecting llvmlite<0.36,>=0.35.0
  Downloading llvmlite-0.35.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (25.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.3 MB 10.9 MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.16.0
  Downloading numpy-1.19.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.5 MB 11.3 MB/s
Collecting pillow>=5.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-8.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.2 MB 3.8 MB/s
Collecting scipy>=1.1.0
  Downloading scipy-1.5.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.8 MB 12.0 MB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy, llvmlite, scipy, pillow, numba, pymatting
Successfully installed llvmlite-0.35.0 numba-0.52.0 numpy-1.19.4 pillow-8.0.1 pymatting-1.1.2 scipy-1.5.4

root@dcda6f2673cb:/# python
Python 3.8.7 (default, Dec 22 2020, 18:46:25)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pymatting_aot.aot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatting_aot.aot'

>>> import pymatting_aot.cc
Failed to import ahead-of-time-compiled modules.
This is expected on first import.
Compiling modules and trying again.
This might take a minute.
Successfully imported ahead-of-time-compiled modules.

>>> import pymatting_aot.aot
>>> pymatting_aot.aot
<module 'pymatting_aot.aot' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymatting_aot/aot.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
```

**Edit 1**: in fact, after looking into cc.py you don't even need to import pymatting_aot.aot after importing pymatting_aot.cc as it will be loaded for you.

**Edit 2**: here is how you could embed compiling the .so from Dockerfile for app engine's custom flex env:

```
~ cat Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8
RUN pip install pymatting && python -c 'import pymatting_aot.cc'
```

Testing:

```
~ docker run -it --rm test:latest
Python 3.8.7 (default, Dec 22 2020, 18:46:25)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymatting_aot.aot
>>>
```

Comment: I've used ```import pymatting_aot.cc``` in GAE console and it fixed the issue when running the API directly using ```gunicorn -w 8 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker servicename:app```. For the deployed version, I've added ```import pymatting_aot.cc``` at the top of the py script and deployed it but still getting the issue of ```No module named 'pymatting_aot.aot'```, also I'm using standard env with no docker. I guess the issue comes when GAE tries to install the requirement ```pymatting``` before accessing the py file.

Comment: Ok, in this case the env wont have CC to compile shared object library. I think I got confused and though that you were working with flex env because you said you were able to run commands in your GAE console, how did you ssh/connect to the standard environment?

Comment: What I mean is the ```Google Cloud Shell``` that is activated from the top right of the google cloud page.

Comment: Cloud Shell is completely separate environment and isn't related to what's being ran inside your app engine container in any way. It does have a compiler and thus can compile the library. App engine std env doesn't.

Comment: I see, is there a way to run ```pymatting_aot.cc``` inside the GAE standard env or add into the requirements file somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it is possible, there is no way to manipulate the content of the image for the container that spins up for your app in std env, apart from specifying the requirements and couple of options in app yaml, which is exactly what flex env is for - it is for when you need more flexibility in what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved yet, try

```
apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

Comment: I get ```E: Unable to locate package python3.8-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-dev'```
Still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `pymatting` inside GAE

```
pip3 install pymatting
```

Comment: I get ```Requirement already satisfied: pymatting in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.1.1)```